# How do I replace a character which is not preceded by \ by [character] globally?

Tags: javascript, regex

For example if string `x = "\\aa\\aa\\a"`
result should look like `"\a[a]\a[a]\a"`

Since javascript doesn't have look behind I am finding it hard to implement this. :(

Comment: Your string should be `"\\aa\\aa\\a"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
'\\aa\\aa\\a'.replace(/(\\)?(.)/g, function($0, $1, $2){
  return $1?$1+$2:'['+$2+']';
}); // "\a[a]\a[a]\a"
```

We walk through string by preceeded and not characters `(\\)?(.)`.

- `$1` will be `\\` if it exists or `undefined` if it was ommited.
- `$2` capture `(.)` part, e.g. any character.
  You can to replace it with `[^\\]` if you want to work with double escapes too.

So, we just analyze `$1` and decide what replacement we want to choose:
`$1+$2` to leave input as is or `'['+$2+']'` to wrap input character.

---

```
'\\aabc\\aa\\a'.replace(/(\\)?(([acl9#])|.)/g, function($0, $1, $2, $3){
return $1 ?               // have we escaped character?
          $1+$2:          // yes
          ($3?            // have we unescaped [acl9#] ?
             '['+$3+']':
             $2           // some other unescaped character
           );
});// "\a[a]b[c]\a[a]\a"
```

---

Also, you can use `$0` argument for restoring:

```
// /(\\)?(?:([acl9#])|.)/g  
// (?: ) is uncaptured group
return $1 ? $0 : ($2 ? '['+$2+']' : $0);
```

Comment: Sorry I don't want all the characters to be affected though I only want l,a,c,9 and # characters to be replaced in this way. :(

Comment: There is nothing about this in your question. Try change `(.)` part to what you want to capture(You must also to match unmatched cases to restore original part same way).